# AWS S3 redirect rule from index.php to index.html

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a public AWS S3 bucket `www.mydomain.com` and I need to redirect `www.mydomain.com/index.php` to `www.mydomain.com/index.html`. The redirect rule that I have defined does not work. A http GET to `www.mydomain.com/index.php` returns 404 not found, because the requested resource does not exist.

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "index.php"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "index.html"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect a request to a different object you need to configure the metadata on the object. The docs give an example of this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#redirect-requests-object-metadata). However, in your case there is not an object against which to redirect.

A workaround here would be to create the `index.php` object and configure the metadata of `index.php` to point to the `index.html` object in the bucket. The linked docs have a sentence on this situation as it is fairly common:

```
Delete the content of page1.html and upload a zero-byte object named page1.html to replace the existing object and redirect page requests.
```

In your case there is not an object to delete so you can simply create a zero-byte object as a placeholder and configure the metadata to redirect.

The instructions on how to do this in either the aws console or via an sdk are in the linked s3 docs.

I just setup a test website for this to confirm and everything works as expected. Here is a screenshot of adding the metadata to the `index.php` object in the bucket.

[image: adding metadata]